# VOD Nginx с помощью тега video

Tags: html5, nginx, видео

Приветствую. Пытался разобраться с mp4 псевдо стримингом Nginx... И так как знаний в этой области не много, возникли вопросы.

Я собрал nginx с --with-http_mp4_module, прописал в конфиге

```
    location /opt/video/mp4/ {
        mp4;
        mp4_buffer_size     1m;
        mp4_max_buffer_size 5m;
    }
```

Теперь для начала стриминга мне достаточно залить обыкновенный mp4 файл и вставить его в html5 video тег? Да видео запускается, но я не уверен, что это псевдостриминг, потому получаю абсолютно идентичный результат, когда я отдаю файл и без модуля --with-http_mp4_module в теге video...

Для кроссплафторменности лучше использовать тег video или плеер наподобие videojs?

Comment: там же для этого специальные директивы vod и application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно [документации](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_mp4_module.html) нужно еще указывать аргумент `start`.

> Если запрос, обрабатываемый этим модулем, не содержит аргументов start
>   и end, дополнительные ресурсы не тратятся, а файл отсылается
>   непосредственно как статический ресурс.

- Речь идет только про флешовый плеер.

Кажется, о том, что на самом деле происходит, могут сказать логи.

- Попробуйте стукнуться по ссылке через curl или wget. Так будет проще отлиживаться.